# Problem using harlequin colorscheme in vim with pathogen

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme, plugin-pathogen

I'm currently configuring vim on my work computer and I'm encountering a problem with the colour scheme.

I'm using pathogen and all of my plugins are working well. I downloaded the harlequin colour scheme and dropped it into my bundle folder just as I have with previous computers. When I go to my vimrc file and type `:colorscheme` I can browse the available options and indeed harlequin is one of them. When I select harlequin however, I just get the default colorscheme. Not surprisingly when I type `colorscheme harlequin` in my vimrc, it just maintains the default.

Suggestions? (here is a copy of my vimrc)

```
 1 "Use pathogen plugin manager
 2 execute pathogen#infect()
 3 
 4 "change colour scheme
 5 colorscheme harlequin
 6 
 7 "set line numbering
 8 set number
 9 
10 "turn on status bar
11 set laststatus=2
12 
13 "syntax and indenting on
14 syntax on
15 filetype plugin indent on
16 
17
```

Comment: Are you using vim within in a terminal window, or a GUI version of vim?

Comment: That colorscheme [is designed to bail out if you don't use a GUI Vim or if Vim thinks your terminal emulator doesn't support 256 colors](https://github.com/nielsmadan/harlequin/blob/master/colors/harlequin.vim#L14-L16).

Comment: I am using terminal window vim. Perhaps I should use a different terminal emulator then

Comment: See: [Using a custom color scheme and setting it as default](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15222/using-a-custom-color-scheme-and-setting-it-as-default). Different colour scheme and terminal, but the same underlying problem: your terminal config reports it doesn't support 256 colours, so the colour scheme doesn't do anything.

Answer (score -1):

romainl found the problem. My terminal didn't have 256 color, which konsole does actually support. Fixed it by changing the path and getting the proper script `256color.pl`