# Using a custom color scheme and setting it as default

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme

I'm just starting with VIM and I'm trying to install this custom color scheme: https://github.com/devnul1/heman

I created a .vim directory on my home directory and inside .vim I created a directory colors, inside that I uploaded the color scheme file:

```
.vim/colors/heman.vim
```

I then created a .vimrc file with this configuration:

```
syntax on
colorscheme heman
set number
```

I know the .vimrc file is working because when I open VIM I get line numbers, but thing is I don't get the custom color scheme.

Am I doing something wrong? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? What is the output of `:colorscheme` after starting up?

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble OK this is weird, color scheme wasn’t working on my Mac at home but now that I openned VIM in my iPhone the custom color scheme is working. Could this be related to the SSH client? Shoulded I restart the server after placing the color scheme file or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I notice that that colorscheme requires a 256 color terminal, based on this towards the beginning:

```
if !has('gui_running') && &t_Co != 256
    finish
endif
```

It's likely that your Mac at home doesn't set the `TERM` environment variable by default to indicate that it supports 256 colors, whereas your phone's terminal emulator/SSH client does.

Check the value of the `TERM` variable (`echo $TERM`); I'm guessing that it's `xterm`, indicating that the terminal does *not* support 256 colors, whereas it should be `xterm-256color` to indicate that it *does*.

Many terminal emulators (e.g. XTerm) still set the `TERM` to `xterm` by default for historical reasons even though they support 256 colors, requiring you to manually override that (to do this in XTerm, you set the following resource: `XTerm*termName: xterm-256color`). I'd imagine you just need to do that for whatever particular terminal emulator you're using on your Mac.

You could also try setting the `TERM` variable manually in your shell before entering VIM, e.g.:

```
TERM=xterm-256color vim
```

or

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
vim
```

Comment: For Terminal.app and iTerm (the only two widely-used term emulators I know of for Mac) this can be done directly in preferences.

Comment: Thanks @villapx It was the TERM setting indeed. I was using Termius both on Mac and on iPhone and oddly they do support xterm-256color on iPhone but not on Mac.

Comment: Thanks @DavidBenKnoble I switched to Terminal.app and found it is configured with xterm-256color by default.